# HTML5 header element not displaying background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I am working on a new HTML5 template.  I am using the `<header></header>` element on the page with a simple logo background image.

```
header{ width:100%; height:100px; background:url(/dev-acn/img/header-logo-bg.jpg) 45px center no-repeat; }
```

Dev page: http://www.bcidaho.com/dev-acn/index.asp

I can see the background Image in PC Chrome, PC FF4, and on MAC FF5, however it does not display in IE6, IE7, or IE8...and when I open the developer tools in IE8 from some reason there is no opening `<header>` element tag in the code inspector just the `</header>` closing tag.

Does IE not recognize the `<header>` element, even if i have properties defined in the style.css? (located: http://www.bcidaho.com/dev-acn/css/style.css )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), which turns the new semantic HTML5 elements into block-level elements so IE can style them. It's a simple hack, so check the source to see exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 4):

> Does IE not recognize the 
>   element, even if i have properties
>   defined in the style.css?

Correct. For versions lower than IE9, you need to use this:

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

You'll also need this CSS:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

For some background information, see:

http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been addressed already, but I found a different solution to this on
http://orderedlist.com/resources/html-css/structural-tags-in-html5/.

Just add this script to the top of the page, and the new HTML5 elements will render correctly in older versions of IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('footer');
    document.createElement('section');
    document.createElement('aside');
    document.createElement('nav');
    document.createElement('article');
</script>
```

Just a nice alternative for us purists who don't want to rely on an outside source. :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the HTML5 issues, you also have some of the parameters in the wrong order for the background style.

Split them up, or put them in the correct order.

The correct order is:

1. background-color
2. background-image
3. background-repeat
4. background-attachment
5. background-position

You can skip some, but the have to be in the right order.

I rarely use the combined (AKA shorthand) version because it's too annoying to remember the order.

Comment: He has the order: image, position, repeat. As far as I know it's not legal to do that.

Comment: Just because it works in one browser doesn't mean it's legal, or that it will work in all.

Comment: It's legal: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background. It works in all browsers.

Comment: @thirtydot I looked at the page you linked, and it confirmed what I said: It's not legal. You need to have the properties in that order, but you can skip some if you want. @stefan-kendall: You should verify the facts before complimenting them.

Comment: @Ariel: My link *does not* confirm what you said - you're misinterpreting it. [The CSS here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjtdY/1/)... [is valid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FrjtdY%2F1%2Fshow%2F&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).

Comment: @thirtydot See here: http://old.nabble.com/ordering-of-background-shorthand-properties-td27399019.html it looks like css3 or css2.1 relaxed the rules. Also notice how the validator reordered the properties when it printed them. And it seems we are not the first to notice the ambiguity: http://csarven.ca/css-background-order-and-w3c-specification-ambiguity-in-browsers When I read the spec I see the BNF in a strict order, but I guess others read it as simply a list of options.